# How to set or map fetch response to modal attributes in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a model `Order` with two nested models `User` and `Hotel`.

```
var User   = Backbone.Model.extend(){ 
                defaults: { name : '----'}
             }
var Hotel  = Backbone.Model.extend(){ 
                defaults: { name : '----'}
             }
var Order  = Backbone.Model.extend(){ 
                  urlRoot: '/order',
                  initialize : function(){
                                    this.set("hotel", new Hotel())
                                    this.set("user", new User())

                               }
             }
```

Here is my view with `fetch`:

```
var OrderPanelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el      : '#page',
    render  : function(options){
        var that = this
        var order = new Order({id: options.id})
        order.fetch({
            success: function(obj){
                console.log(order.get('user')); //this still print the default value
                console.log(obj.get('user')); //this also prints the default value
                console.log(obj) //this has the attributes sent by server
            }
        })
    }
})
```

**TL;DR**

My Question is: How to set the fetch response data in the model. Do I have to set the data manually? Am I missing anything?

Comment: We can't really see what the response from your server is. If that response doesn't contain `hotel` or `user`, the model *will* use the default values you defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fetch will set the model automatically. Ofcourse the server response should be a correct JSON model.

I think you question is, why Hotel and User models arent filled. Well, the fetch only sets all values. It will just merge your User/Hotel model from the initialize with the array/object from the server. Probably overwriting it. A correct way would be to make these models is:

```
 order.fetch({
            success: function(obj){
                order.set('user', new User( order.get('user') ) );
                order.set('hotel', new Hotel( order.get('hotel') ) ); 
             }
 });
```